# Библиотека захвата и анализа изображения + эмуляция нажатия мыши

Tags: c#, mouse-event, распознавание-символов

В поисках готовой современной библиотеки захвата и анализа изображения + эмуляции нажатия мыши. Требуется таким способом взаимодействовать с иной запущенной программой. Подскажите, что актуальное на сегодняшний день есть в этой области? Или обойтись родным API?

Интересен личный опыт и плюсы/минусы в использовании.

Comment: Какого рода программа? Есть стандартные способы захвата изображения с экрана, взаимодействие с мышкой через API прекрасно работает. Только если вы это решили сделать с играми, то все эти действия легко обнаруживаются античитами с соответствующими последствиями.

Comment: А можно по подробнее, про античиты, можно ссылками. Я так понимаю что место селекта-щелчка мыши должно быть рандомным по области элемента. Ещё на что обратить внимание?

Comment: На уголовный кодекс обратить внимание... | Для написания ботов хороши AutoIt и AutoHotKey.